# How do I figure out what options to use with jQuery's support function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working with the following javascript code(in order to put a calendar-picker in an SSRS page), but I realized it didn't even work because it's deprecated and not supported.  They said that the `.browser.webkit` function should not be used..

```
$(document).ready(
    function () { 
        if ($.browser.webkit) { 
            $($(":hidden[id*='DatePickers']").val().split(","))
                .each(function (i, item) {
                var h = $("table[id*='ParametersGrid'] span")
                    .filter(function (i) {
                        var v = "[" + $(this).text() + 
                                "]"; 
                        return (v != null && v.indexOf(item) >= 0); })
                            .parent("td").next("td").find("input").datepicker(
                                { 
                                    showOn: "button", 
                                    buttonImage: '/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.calendar.gif', 
                                    buttonImageOnly: true, 
                                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
                                    changeMonth: true, 
                                    changeYear: true 
                                    }); }); } });
```

So on [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) they say to use jQuery.support, I have no idea how to do this.
Would I put something like this:

```
$.browser.support(ajax)
```

Comment: You should first isolate which part of that code won't work, for example, on IE. At first look I can't see anything strange (but I don't remember how default datepicker is rendered with browsers other than IE).

Comment: `$.support` (not `$.browser.support`) isn't a function, it's an object.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: @RocketHazmat - ah OK thnks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documented properties on the page you linked to are all booleans, so you can just switch on them:

```
if ($.support.ajax) {
    // ajax is supported
} else {
    // ajax is not supported
}
```

Comment: Is him testing for ajax support?

Comment: @Adriano - yes, among other things

Comment: @Adel: is there any ajax on the function you posted? The point of $.support is to check for specific features instead of the "uncontrolled" support for a browsers family...

Comment: @Adriano-  yeah I forgot to mention - there was a print functionality that uises AJAX - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504567/Print-button-Date-picker-in-SSRS-Reports-for-Non-I#_rating

Comment: @Adel again I don't think the point of that check is if you has Ajax or not (besides an example of how to use $.support). In that code they added that check because datepicker and print are supported on IE but not in webkit browsers. You'll execute that code in IE too (unnecessary). In that code you MUST check for the browser, not for a feature.

Comment: @Adriano - Ah, understood... so, I must modify it. OK. will do!

Answer (score 0):

Just read the page you've mentioned :)

```
if (jQuery.support.ajax) { // your code}
```